# Spring-Webflux : Flatmap is making list empty

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am using reactive programming with Webflux to write my REST api. I have response object below like this:

```
class Account
{
  private Customer customer;
  private List<Accounts> accountList;

}
```

I am setting customer and accountList using getters and setters. I can see both populated correctly, but my final response is always being returned with the right "Customer", but it is an empty account list even though I can see the data in Account List.

```
return request
            .bodyToMono(PersonRequest.class)
            .doOnNext { logger.info("Request : $it") }
            .flatMap(validateRequest(it))
            .flatMap(personService::getPerson)
            .doOnNext (logger.info("Final Response : $it"))
           .flatMap(ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)::bodyValue);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can see "Final Response" log printing correctly but, after that I see an empty list in my JSON response.

Comment: post validateRequest method

Comment: It’s just validating the incoming requests like fields are null or not. I don’t think it has to do anything with response.Final response log is good. But I believe last flatmap is making list empty.

Comment: Post more of the code

Answer (score 0):

This is happenning due to "private var" inside my kotlin data classes.removing private worked for me.